# Chromatic Aberration with Mac Mini

Tags: hardware, mac-mini, screen, thunderbolt, vga

I recently bought a Mac Mini Late 2014 intermediate version of the three available.
I have the following issue.

Sometimes when I turn the Mac Mini on or from standby I get this chromatic aberration

[image]

[image]

After a reboot everything comes back to normal.
In the beginning I thought it was an hardware problem so I went back to the Apple Store and they changed my Mac Mini. However when I plugged in the new one it gave me the same problem! I also tried to test this effect on 3 different monitors and I got the same issues.

Maybe is it something related to the Thunderbolt -> VGA adapter or the VGA cable? Or is it something related to software?

Comment: Have you tried using another adapter/cable?

Comment: Not yet indeed! Also because the vga / thunderbolt adaptor works fine my 15inch retina late 2013. But it is something that I should definitely try!

Comment: You could also try booting the Mac Mini in safe mode by holding shift when booting. I don't think this will change anything, but it's worth a try. Priority would be testing different cables.

How to boot in safe mode:
http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262

Comment: Looks like a color profile problem. Have you gone to the Displays in System Prefs and reset the profile after updating to Mavericks? I had to do that on my mini.

Comment: So did you have the same issue? I bought the mini directly with Yosemite. However I'll try to see if your approach works.

Comment: Profile changed on me when I *updated* to yosemite. In your case the Mac may have just auto-chosen an innapropriate profile.